# Is there a way to use plot () using layers in pine-script with tradingview?

Tags: pine-script

Code:

**plot(lower1, color=#FFFF00, transp=0, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_circles)**

**plot(lower2, color=#000000, transp=0, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_area)****

I want to draw an area and a few points above it.

The problem I have is that the points are drawn and then the area is drawn on top of the points and covers the points, and I can't see the points.

I have changed the lines, that is, the area is drawn first and then the points, but it throws me a code error, with another error.

I need this code to draw the points and then the area.

**Is there a way to use plot () using layers in pine-script with tradingview?**

**Help me please, thanks.**

Comment: What do you mean? Please provide some more details and/or a screenshot of what you would like to see.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Please edit your question and post the entire script you currently have. That way, the community can help you assess what's wrong, and how to improve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have improved the question, thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: No, not like that. Please post the entire script that you have, that gives you the error.